How to fetch the key size of an azure key vault existing key?
I created a key in azure key vault programmatically using Java SDK.
Response<KeyVaultKey> createKeyResponse = keyClient.createRsaKeyWithResponse(new CreateRsaKeyOptions(id)
                        .setKeySize(keySize), Context.NONE);

Later I want to fetch the key details using the below code.
KeyVaultKeyIdentifier identifier = new KeyVaultKeyIdentifier(keyId);
KeyVaultKey key = keyClient.getKey(identifier.getName(),identifier.getVersion());

The KeyVaultKey does not seem to contain the key size in it. It has properties like expiresOn , CreatedOn , algorithms , operations etc. But not the size.
So, is there some way to get the key size of a specific azure keyname , version pair.
Thanks in advance.

Use the below code to fetch the RSA KeySize of the Key:
byte[] n = key.getKey().getN();
int keySize = new BigInteger(1, n).bitLength();


I have used below code to retrieve the RSA Key Size of the Key from Azure Key Vault.
String keyVaultName = "<keyvaultname>";
        String keyVaultUri = "https://" + keyVaultName + ".vault.azure.net";

        System.out.printf("key vault name = %s and key vault URI = %s \n", keyVaultName, keyVaultUri);

KeyClient keyClient = new KeyClientBuilder()
          .vaultUrl(keyVaultUri)
          .credential(new DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder().build())
          .buildClient();
String keyname="kprkey";
CreateRsaKeyOptions options = new CreateRsaKeyOptions(keyname)
             .setKeySize(4096);

keyClient.createRsaKeyWithResponse(options,null);
System.out.println("Created key successfully");
System.out.println("Retrieving key details");
KeyVaultKey key1 = keyClient.getKey(keyname);
        
System.out.println("Your key's ID is '" + key1.getKey() + "'.");
byte[] n = key1.getKey().getN();
int keySize = new BigInteger(1, n).bitLength();
System.out.println("Your key's Size is '" + keySize+ "'.");


Key got created in the keyvault in Azure:



Key Size of the Key in Portal:



Console Response:



It works. Thanks.
Any idea on why there is no function to directly access the keySize.
Also, Why not calculate the key size like
int keySize = key.getKey().getN().length * 8; Why convert it to  new BigInteger?
Thanks in advance.
